# Surveys on Network Coding

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory, survey, ni.networking-internet

I want to start learning about Network Coding:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_coding

Do you know any good survey (e.g. from IEEE Surveys and Tutorials) on the above subjects. I found some university courses on google but I'd like some recommendations from people who already read and know a good source.

Thanks
Vasilis

Comment: Seems more like a computer networks question, not a theoretical science question. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) for the scope of cstheory.

Comment: I have no idea what you are looking for, because network coding (such as butterfly network) and content delivery networks (such as Akamai) are very different things.

Comment: Emina Soljanin at Alcatel-Lucent Labs works on network coding and content delivery networks. She has written survey articles on network coding. See her web page. http://ect.bell-labs.com/who/emina/. You can also check out her papers on content delivery via network coding and other means on the ArXiv.

Comment: @Kaveh
Network coding seems pretty theoretical to me. Of course everything has practical implications but it is purely mathematics. A practical question would be something like "is there any API for coding implementation?"

Comment: @Tsuyoshi
I want some resources on these two different subjects. Not one that mixes both.

Comment: @Chandra
Thank you for the only useful answer

Comment: @Vasilis: I didn't meant that this is a practical question, I meant the area that studies this type of question, i.e. this type of questions are studied mainly in computer networks community (AFAIK), and the researcher in computer networks do use mathematics, that doesn't make it a question in the area of _theoretical computer science_, i.e. there is a difference between a "theoretical question in computer science" and a "theoretical computer science" question. Researchers in computer networks probably can answer your question better.

Comment: ps: 1. I think it might be better if you separate the two questions and focus on one of them. 2. I don't think this question deserves down-votes.

Comment: @Chandra make this an answer ? I think it's worth being one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Suresh's request (he is the boss after all) I am making my comment above an answer.

Emina Soljanin at Alcatel-Lucent Labs works on network coding and content delivery networks. She has written survey articles on network coding. See her web page. ect.bell-labs.com/who/emina. You can also check out her papers on content delivery via network coding and other means on the ArXiv.

I also want to say that network coding is a topic of much interest to theoretical computer science - there are several papers in TCS on this topic.

Comment: "he is the boss after all" ? Ahem :) ?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the following two monographs on the topic:

[1] C. Fragouli and E. Soljanin, Network Coding Fundamentals, Foundations and Trends in Networking, Now Publishers, June 2007.

[2] C. Fragouli and E. Soljanin, Network Coding Applications, Foundations and Trends in Networking, Now Publishers, January 2008.

Answer (score 3):

Vasili, I think a good reference is anything by Raymond Yeung (he is one of the inventors of network coding).
The following is one of the most famous monographs on the subject:

R. W. Yeung, S.-Y. R. Li, N. Cai, and Z. Zhang, Network Coding Theory, now Publishers, 2005
http://iest2.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~whyeung/netcode/monograph.html
IMHO it is a really good read.

Here is also a book on info theory and network coding, again by Prof. Raymond http://iest2.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/~whyeung/book2/

Answer (score 1):

Check out our survey:

Michele Sanna and Ebroul Izquierdo, "[A Survey of Linear Network Coding and Network Error Correction Code Constructions and Algorithms](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/2011/857847)", 2011